# randomForest out-of-bag variable importance

Tags: r, random-forest, variance

I am trying to understand how a %var be over 100.

I am using the script :

```
require(randomForest)

start <- "B_fixed"
suffix <- ".txt"
dataDir <- "/Users/Desktop/"


mod1 <- read.table(paste(dataDir,start,suffix,sep=""),sep="\t",header=T)


form <- as.formula(Ksat_f~.)

Ksat_rf <- randomForest(form, data=mod1[c(1:14)],na.action=na.omit, ntree=1000, 
              replace=F,importance=T, do.trace=50, keep.forest=T,keep.inbag=T)
```

I get an output of:

```
     |      Out-of-bag   |
Tree |      MSE  %Var(y) |
  50 |    3.258   114.85 |
 100 |     3.06   107.87 |
 150 |    3.096   109.12 |
 200 |    3.054   107.66 |
 250 |    3.014   106.25 |
 300 |    3.012   106.15 |
 350 |    2.978   104.96 |
 400 |    2.971   104.73 |
 450 |    2.952   104.06 |
 500 |    2.941   103.66 |
 550 |    2.936   103.49 |
 600 |    2.928   103.22 |
 650 |    2.933   103.39 |
 700 |    2.934   103.44 |
 750 |     2.92   102.94 |
 800 |    2.929   103.23 |
 850 |    2.953   104.10 |
 900 |    2.957   104.24 |
 950 |    2.951   104.04 |
1000 |    2.931   103.32 |
```

This is using 14 variables..... If I use one variable the %var can come out 145%.

Anything would help.

thanks

-t

Comment: Please edit your post and make it a full reproducible example (beginning with the `library` calls that load the required packages).

Comment: What does your y-var look like?

Comment: @triBaker your edit is close but not exactly reproducible.  You cannot refer to a data set, only you have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 145% tells you, that your model is far more wrong than right

I admit that is slightly confusing. The `%Var(y)` refer to the percentage variance of error compared to total target variance. Whereas `% Var explained:` refer to percentage variance explained by model.

Notice: 105.15% + (-5.15%) = 100%

In the reproducible example below I shuffle/permute the targets(y's) so the RF model have no chance to predict. You see it performs very bad, as the error exceeds 100% and as the explained variance is less than 0%. At 0% explained variance your model has same accuracy as predicting any observation equal to the grand mean.

```
set.seed(1)

library(randomForest)
X <- data.frame(replicate(5,rnorm(1000)))
y <- apply(X,1,sum)
y <- sample(y)
Data <- data.frame(X,y)

form <- as.formula(y~.)

rf <- randomForest(form, data=Data,na.action=na.omit,
                   ntree=1000,replace=F,importance=T,
                   do.trace=50, keep.forest=T,keep.inbag=T)

     |      Out-of-bag   |
Tree |      MSE  %Var(y) |
  50 |     5.81   108.91 |
 100 |    5.671   106.31 |
 150 |    5.651   105.95 |
1000 |    5.609   105.15 |

print(rf)

Call:
 randomForest(formula = form, data = Data, ntree = 1000, replace = F,      importance = T, do.trace = 50, keep.forest = T, keep.inbag = T,      na.action = na.omit) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 1000
No. of variables tried at each split: 1

          Mean of squared residuals: 5.608769
                    % Var explained: -5.15
```

Comment: You're welcome :) btw this is explained variance of out-of-bag samples, not variable importance. Variable importance(RF regression) is the decrease in out-of-bag explained variance due to permutation of a given variable after training, before predictions.